# typescript disallows circular references when there are generic parameters?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a type error in the following example `Type alias 'bar2' circularly references itself.ts(2456)`

```
type foo = {
  bars: bar[];
};

//works fine
type bar = foo;

type foo2<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  bars: bar2[];
} & T;

//TYPE ERROR
type bar2<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = foo2<T>;
```

It seems like circular types are not allowed when there are generics involved? Is that true? Is there a way to make this work?

I originally had something like `foo` and `bar`, but I needed to add a generic param to `foo` and ended up with something like `foo2` and `bar2`. But i get the type error now so I'm not sure the best way forward.

The reason I need `bar` is that while it happens to just be an alias for `foo` right now, in the future, it could extend `foo` and add new fields. So I can't just throw away `bar` and use `foo` everywhere. It's semantically different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work:

```js
type foo = {
    bars: bar[];
};

//works fine
type bar = foo;

type foo2<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> = {
    bars: bar2<T>[]; // <---- bar2 expects generic argument
} & T;

// works fine
type bar2<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = foo2<T>;
```

Just add generic argument to `bar2`

Comment: oh good call. I guess I forgot the generic param. Thanks!